# How do I convert RGB to float values?

Tags: c#, .net, colors

im getting 3 ints: R, G, B
I want to use this colors for something where i need to enter 3 floats: R, G, B.
How do I "convert" the int to a float? Because in the float 1 is the highest

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please describe more about the requirement and the problem, share some examples on inputs and expected outputs. Also take a look at [ASK].

Comment: `float red = int_red / 255f;`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depending on the range of the `int` RGB values, you can simply divide by the maximum brightness value allowed to convert to `float`.

For example, if the `int` ranges from 0 - 255 (e.g. HTML Color Codes), then you can use

```
float fR = intR / 255.0F;
```

and so on for G and B.

Comment: what is iR?
Is it the int?

Comment: @RarePotato8DE Yes that is the `int` R value.

Comment: Why is it 255 and not 256? Aren't there 256 possible values for each color?

Comment: @DidiKohen Yes, but the range of values is `0` to `255`. You want to match those values to the range `0.0` - `1.0`, you want `0` to return `0` and you want `255` to return `1.0`.